# Please identify diode

Tags: diodes

This is a diode for a 9500-HBE Dock. I can not seem to be able to identify it.  It's connected to the DC jack. Thanks for your help.[image]

Comment: What does it say on it?

Comment: 736 AX. There are some characters before the 7 too.

Comment: It's most likely reverse polarity protection diode. Almost any schottky in that package will do the job.

Comment: https://www.mouser.co.uk/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Diodes-Rectifiers/Zener-Diodes/_/N-awhng?keyword=736A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [SMBJ10CA](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/s/m/smbj5.0a-smbj170a_diodes.pdf) from Diodes Inc, a transient voltage suppressor.

[image]

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me.